# How to move object left, right, up and down using KeyListener does not seem to be working

Tags: java

Trying to make my player move using the left, right, up and down arrow, Have class called InputHandler that implements KeyListener and have code in KeyPressed such as VK_LEFT etc, tried using Switch and If Else statements maybe I'm being abit stupid

```
 Method to handle key presses captured by the GameGUI. The method calls
     * the game engine doTurn method to process a game turn for ANY key press,
     * but if the up, down, left or right arrow keys are pressed it also calls a
     * method in the engine to update the game by moving the player.
     *
     * @param e A KeyEvent object generated when a keyboard key is pressed
```

```
**
     * Handles the movement of the player when attempting to move in the game.
     * This method is automatically called by the InputHandler class when the
     * user has presses one of the arrow keys on the keyboard. The method should
     * check which direction for movement is required, by checking which
     * character was passed to this method (see parameter description below). If
     * the tile above, below, to the left or to the right is clear then the
     * player object should have its position changed to update its position in
     * the game window. If the target tile is not empty then the player should
     * not be moved, but other effects may happen such as giving a customer
     * food, or picking up food etc. To achieve this, the target tile should be
     * checked to determine the type of tile (food, table, wall etc.) and
     * appropriate methods called or attribute values changed.
```

```
@param direction A char representing the direction that the player should
     * move. U is up, D is down, L is left and R is right.
```

These are what I have been told to implement in the code but the arrow keys don't seem to make the player move

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                engine.movePlayer('L');
                break;  //handle left arrow key
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                engine.movePlayer('R');
                break;//handle right arrow
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                engine.movePlayer('U');
                break;      //handle up arrow
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                engine.movePlayer('D');
                break;  //handle down arrow
        }
        engine.doTurn();
```

This code above is the code I have been told to edit so that when the left arrow is pressed the player will move to the left, The code above is in the InputHandler class

```
public void movePlayer(char direction) {
switch (direction) {
            case 'U':
                // update player position and game state to move player up
                break;
            case 'L':
                // update player position and game state to move player left
                break;
            case 'R':
                // update player position and game state to move player right
                break;
            case 'D':
                // update player position and game state to move player down
                break;
            default:
                // code to execute if direction is none of the above
                break;
        }
```

The code above is the code I have added, The code above is in the GameEngine class

Now when ever I try to run this project there is no compiler error but the arrow keys don't seem to move the player

Comment: Like most questions relating to `KeyListener`, you should be using the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.  I'd also place debug statements in your code to test what flows are been executed and without knowing your update workflow, make sure the UI is been repainted

Comment: How should the character move when you didn't implement the actual movement? Your `movePlayer()` method does nothing.

Comment: Right, So How would I make my player move because  I thought that since I made VK_LEFT as 'L' if I just mentioned the letter 'L' in the gameEngine class that it would pick up the keypressed. And also would I possibly need to add .GetLocation so that the movements update automatically?

Comment: I have been told to implent KeyListener and not something else like KeyBinding

Comment: You did combine the key with letter "L", but didn't tell the engine what "L" is supposed to mean. As you can see, that switch doesn't do anything. You now need to move your player on the screen. We can't tell how to do that, because we don't know how your code looks like.

Comment: See: [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/)

Comment: This is the issue, I'm facing My code which is as follow public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
engine.movePlayer('L');
break;  //handle left arrow key
case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
engine.movePlayer('R');
break;//handle right arrow
case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
engine.movePlayer('U');
break;      //handle up arrow
case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
engine.movePlayer('D');
break;  //handle down arrow
}
engine.doTurn(); but the issue is I need to make the letter 'D' link in the GameEngine class which I don't understand

Comment: Your `keyPressed` implementation is probably fine. You can add some print statements to check that the cases in your switch block are being entered correctly. As @Tom says, you need to modify `movePlayer` so that the state of the game changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the code for `GameEngine` class. If it contains the `x` and `y` position of the player on screen, you need to update it accordingly.

For example if you have the `x` and `y` coordinates of player (which you should have considering you need to move the player), you can do the following:

```
public void movePlayer(char direction) {
        switch (direction) {
            case 'U':
                // update player position and game state to move player up
                y -= 1;
                break;
            case 'L':
                // update player position and game state to move player left
                x -= 1;
                break;
            case 'R':
                // update player position and game state to move player right
                x += 1;
                break;
            case 'D':
                // update player position and game state to move player down
                y += 1;
                break;
            default:
                // code to execute if direction is none of the above
                break;
        }
```

This is a very basic implementation without considering speed and friction and assuming the coordinate system's `(0,0)` starts from top left of the screen.